# Python Instance Object: Invalid Syntax Error

Tags: python

To start with. 2 things to be aware of. I’m a novice Python coder and secondly the code below is part of a section from the book I’m using to learn Python
The problem I have is that when I run the code its returning an invalid syntax error at line 4 in the “Bird” program. I have checked what I typed and retyped it but I’m still getting the same error. This is my first time dealing with Instance Objects in Python so I’ve probably missed something obvious. Any pointers would be appreciated.The output should be as follows:

Class Instances of:
A base class to define bird properties
Number of birds: 1
Polly says:  Squak, Squak
Number of birds: 2
Harry says: Tweet, tweet

```
BIRD code
class Bird:
    '''A base class to define bird properties'''
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, chat):
        self.sound = chat
        Bird.count += 1
    def talk(self):
        return self.sound


INSTANCE code
from bird import *
print('\nClass instances of:\n' , Bird_doc_)
polly = Bird( 'Squak, squak!')
print('\nNumber of Birds:' , polly.count)
print('Polly Says: ' , polly.talk())
harry = Bird( 'Tweet tweet')
print('\nNumber of Birds:' , harry.count)
print('Harry says:' , harry.talk())
```

Comment: You miss a space after "def" :)

Comment: Many thanks. Issue now resolved & output as it should be

Comment: It's always good to accept the valid answer, so that your question does not appear in the unanswered section anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors:

1. There should be an space between `def` and `_init_`.
2. The "constructor" should be `__init__` (two underscores). This was defined to be the default "constructor".